# Is there a way to selectList without any filter or select options in Persistent Haskell?

Tags: haskell, yesod

Good day.

I'm learning [Yesod](http://www.yesodweb.com/) a few weeks (I am pretty new to Haskell) by writing a little project.I used MongoDB as the DB and accessing it by persistent-mongoDB.
When I want to run a query which have no any conditions or sorting stuff, e.g.

```
IN MONGODB SHELL
> db.comments.find();
```

I can not find a correct way at least in [the Yesod Book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent).

I tried to write a identical as a workaround.

```
IN YESOD REPL
*Application> db $ selectList [CommentContent !=. ""] []
```

But it sucks...

The same issue in a transact-sql query. e.g.

```
IN YESOD REPL
*Application> db $ count [CommentContent !=. "" ]
```

Comment: Just guessing: try `db $ selectList [] []` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write what type you want

```
myData :: [Entity YOUR_ENTITY_HERE] <- selectList [] []
```

(I used `ScopedTypeVariables` here but is not needed if type can be inferred in other way)

Comment: Thanks a lot.Could you give me a suggestion for count ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "for count?" `Database.Persist.Query` ;)

Comment: Another way to allow the compiler to infer the type of the `Entity` is to specify the type of the `Filter` or `SelectOpt` (e.g. `users <- runDB $ selectList ([] :: [Filter User]) []`), which is common in the Persistent/Yesod codebase. I prefer @josejuan's way, personally.

Comment: @MaxGabriel , You solved my counting problem <!-- language: lang-haskell -->
    haskell db $ count ([]::[Filter Comment])